# Read a text file from a URL line by line, print to a txt file and edit while being printed

Tags: java

This program read each line of the shirt size file available here: https://bbmedia.dmacc.edu/CIS/CIS171/shirtsizes.txt and write all the
people who have order small shirts into a file called
"smallshirts.txt", medium orders into a "mediumshirts.txt" file, large
orders into a "largeshirts.txt" file and finally extra large shirts into "extralargeshirts.txt" file.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
      
public class SortShirtSizes {
    /**
     * This main method will get a file from the URL and separate it into different txt files
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
        try {

        /*getting the txt from the URL*/

        String address = "https://bbmedia.dmacc.edu/CIS/CIS171/shirtsizes.txt";
        URL pageLocation = new URL(address);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());

         /*names of txt files*/

        PrintWriter outToSmall = new PrintWriter("smallshirts.txt");
        PrintWriter outToMed = new PrintWriter("mediumshirts.txt");
        PrintWriter outToLarge = new PrintWriter("largeshirts.txt");
        PrintWriter outToXl = new PrintWriter("extralargeshirts.txt");
         
        outToSmall.println("");
         
        String small = "";
         
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                small = in.nextLine();
                
                 /*print to txt files*/

                if (small.contains("S,")) {
                    outToSmall.println(small);
                }else if (small.contains("M,")) {
                    outToMed.println(small);
                }else if (small.contains("XL,")) {
                    outToXl.println(small);
                }else if (small.contains("L,")) {
                    outToLarge.println(small);
                }
            }
         
        in.close();
        outToSmall.close();
        outToMed.close();
        outToLarge.close();
        outToXl.close();
         
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("https://bbmedia.dmacc.edu/CIS/CIS171/shirtorders2022.txt is not available.");
        }    
    }
}
```

An example of the output:

```
 S,Darsie,Rigmand
 M,Feodor,Lornsen
 L,Klement,Antunes
 XL,Carleton,Van Leeuwen
```

I want to remove the S, M, L, XL, and the , between the first and lastname.

Comment: You would be better off processing this as a CSV file.  There are CSV libraries available.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. But I am a fan of using libraries when there are some available.
What you could do is use the [Apache Commons CSV Library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html) to read the Comma Separated File. Get the information and do whatever you need with it.
To add the library, here is the [Maven Repo link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv).

Example:

```java
URL url = new URL("https://bbmedia.dmacc.edu/CIS/CIS171/shirtsizes.txt");

Reader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()); // Reading the Content of the online FIle

CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.Builder
        .create()
        .setDelimiter(",")
        .setHeader("size", "first_name", "last_name")
        .build(); // Setting the headers and delimiters for this specific format

CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, format);

for(CSVRecord record : csvParser)
{
    String size = record.get("size");
    String firstName = record.get("first_name");
    String lastName = record.get("last_name");
    
    // Do whatever you want with the information above.

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't covered CSV in class yet so I'm not really sure what that is.